# How do I strip the first character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am constructing a URL and I have

```
escape($('#count_of_stations').html()
```

The problem is the value will come in like this

```
1 station
2 stations
```

I need to strip everything other then the first character, so is there a way to sent it with the " station(s)"?

Comment: What if there are 10 stations? Do you still want just the 1st char?

Comment: Your title says "strip the first character" while in the question you say "strip everything other than the first character". Which do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would using `substring` work?

```
escape($('#count_of_stations').html().substring(0, 1));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
parseInt($('#count_of_stations').html())
```

It will discard the later non-numeric characters.

Comment: +1 even though the PO didn't explicitly say it, i am guessing he wants the number value.

Answer (score 0):

if the wording is consistent, i'd just use a replace.

$('#count_of_stations').text($('#count_of_stations').text().relace('station', 'stations'));